# how to code cosine taylor series without explicit factorial function

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to compute the cosine of an input x (in radians) without explicitly using math.factorial function?

i've tried a nested for loop for computing the factorial term (see code below). i also assigned an arbitrary n (n = 85) for the number of terms to be added. i also haven't figured out how to actually determine the actual n sufficient enough so that the next term added is < 10e-7, hence breaking the loop

```
x = float(input()) #input angle x in radians

while True:
    term = numerator / denominator
    if abs(term) < 10e-7:
        break

    n = 85 #test 85 terms

    for j in range(0, 2*n + 1):
        sgn = (-1)**j
        numerator = sgn * (x**(2*j))
        #denominator
        for c in range(0, j + 1):
            if c == 0:
                denominator = 1
            else:
                denominator *= c
        partial_sum += numerator / denominator

print(partial_sum)
```

the only meaningful result i get is for cos(0) = 1. i tried some values such as 3.14 and its output isn't even close to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change something:

```
x = float(input()) #input angle x in radians

while True:
    term = numerator / denominator
    if abs(term) < 10e-7:
        break

    n = 30 #test 30 terms   **change here,n is too large**

    for j in range(0, 2*n + 1):
        sgn = (-1)**j
        numerator = sgn * (x**(2*j))
        #denominator
        for c in range(0, 2*j + 1): # **change here**
            if c == 0:
                denominator = 1
            else:
                denominator *= c
        partial_sum += numerator / denominator

print(partial_sum)
```

Comment: thanks!! it worked. i failed to notice that extra 2* term (its supposed to be 2j!)!!